# Receiving a TypeError for UDP scan data

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

Using the [Local Home SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/local) developer preview for Google Assistant, I'm receiving a `TypeError` from my application during `IDENTIFY` that was previously working correctly. The error is claiming that `UdpScanData` is not a valid string when I try to decode the payload.

Example code:

```
const device = identifyRequest.inputs[0].payload.device;
const response = Buffer.from(device.udpScanData, "hex");
```

How do I access the UDP discovery payload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **0.2.0** update to the developer preview SDK, we have migrated the `UdpScanData` parameter to be an interface instead of just a type alias for `string` (see the updated [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/local/interfaces/smarthome.intentflow.udpscandata)) to improve consistency with the other scan data types.

To access the response payload for a UDP scan in the latest SDK, update your `package.json` dependencies to use v0.2.0:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@google/local-home-sdk": "^0.2.0"
  }
}
```

Then, access the payload using the new `data` property:

```
const device = identifyRequest.inputs[0].payload.device;
const scanData = device.udpScanData;
const response = Buffer.from(scanData.data, "hex");
```